candle counter in Tradingview
i want to make a counter that can count how many 1 minuttes candles been printet i tradingview since yesterday 23:00. I have tried to get help from ChatGPT, but NO luck ?
I hope someone here can help me.
Thanks.
Br mike-kaast
i have tryied the flowwing:
//@version=5
indicator("Candles Since 23:00 Previous Day", overlay=true)

// Deklarer variabel med type
var int candlesSince23 = na

// Beregn antallet af 1-minutslys siden kl. 23:00 i går
if (hour == 0 and minute == 0)
    candlesSince23 := 0
else if (hour == 0)
    candlesSince23 := bar_index - 1 

// Tegn en tæller på indikatorens område
var label counter_label = label.new(x=na, y=na, text="", xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.abovebar,          style=label.style_label_right, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white)

// Opdater tælleren
label.set_xy(counter_label, bar_index, high)
label.set_text(counter_label, "Candles since 23:00 Previous Day: " + str.tostring(candlesSince23))

BUT this dosent work, it prints af wrong number of 13344 ???

you don't need bar_index. you can use the same var candlesSince23
something like that:
if (hour == 0 and minute == 0)
    candlesSince23 := 0
else
    candlesSince23 := candlesSince23[1] + 1

